# Alfresco all parents of a folder

Tags: tree, directory, parent, alfresco

I'm working with alfresco 5.0.d. 
Is there a way to find all parents of a node ?

In a javascript webscript i want to get  the parent  folder tree of  a specific folder until documentary library.

There must be a function which returns in one call the  folder tree i want. But I don't know the function.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you just mean you want the primary path of a node? eg `/app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:email_templates/cm:activities` ? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of the ScriptNode API to get path details

```
qnamePath
    A read-only QName type path to this node
displayPath
    A read-only display path to this node
```

then with the string operation you could convert it in required format.